# How to query a table sql?

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and I need to query a table for any email addresses, I got that working:

```
Select rname FROM PERSON;
```

But I need to also return the name(first(fname) and last(lanme)) of anyone with an email address in the table, not everyone has an email listed though. How would I do that because right now it is only returning the emails.

Comment: It usually helps if you add a tag to your question indicating which database you are using, e.g. sql-server or mysql. Also, do you know the names of the columns in table `PERSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative syntax to the previous answers:

```
SELECT lname, fname, email FROM person WHERE email = email 
ORDER BY lname --or whatever column you want
```

The WHERE clause will get only the rows that has a value on the email column of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
Select * 
FROM PERSON;
```

You will see all the columns. Then select the ones you want:

```
select email, fname, lname
from person
where email is not null
order by email
```

Comment: `top 100` is SQL-Server syntax, isn't it? Pardon my ignorance, but where is it mentioned that the OP is using SQL-Server?

Comment: @Abra, ok, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all records by using `select * from table name`, after that you can use 
`select column names from table name` after that where condition to check whether that record has email or not so your query will go like this:

```
select fname,lname,rname , email from person where email is not null order by fname
```